# Average of minimum and maximum in SQL

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, average

I am trying to find the average of the minimum and maximum in SQL, but my code doesn't work.

```
SELECT AVG(MIN(Num) + MAX(Num)) 
FROM Table1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by 2:

```
SELECT (MIN(Num) + MAX(Num)) / 2
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: @Jackson, yes with a subquery. In MS Access SQL, you cannot combine multiple aggregates.